# parse text form footer of lots of dot files and copy to sharepoint library column

Tags: parsing, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have lot of files esp. word templates also excel or pdf. these files are saved in a library in sharepoint online.
I want to parse the text in the left footer of each document which contains letters, numbers, punctuation marks and special characters.

This text should be entered in the sharepoint library in the respective row in a special column and if there is no text in the footer, it should be left empty and go to the next document until the end of the library

I wanted to solve it with power automate but didn't find a way to do so. I don't know how to start and define the flow.